# ASP.NET MVC3 linking posts to the account models using code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a newly created ASP.net MVC3 project with all the defaults. I am using the approach to build the database. I come from a PHP background and this is my first attempt at a ASP.net project.

I created a new model called "posts" and I want to link it to the built in accounts/users system that came with the default project.

Only signed in users can add posts, and I want to know what user added what post. I want to link the posts to a single user.

In PHP I would create a FK in the posts table to the users table "posts_id" and when a user adds a new post I would fill in that field with the users's id. But there does not seem to be a ID field in the account model.

**Questions**

- How do I link a model to the default account system build in to ASP.net MVC3 using code first approach?
- How do I query for user fields from a view in the post controller?

Links to a tutorials would work for me. 
Thanks

Comment: This is the best tutorial (in my opinion) http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

FKs like `posts_id` is a database style reference. The object oriented way of representing that data is by giving the Account object a `ICollection<Post>` and by giving each Post object an `Account` reference field.

E.g.

```
public class Post
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As for retrieving this data, I would suggest a repository-style service class which would be responsible for saving/loading objects to & from the DB. I am not sure exactly how the Account records get persisted in the template MVC app so I can't say how it would tie into that data. I have always used my own User DB table and thrown away all that build in Microsoft account stuff.

Good luck!